# How to change Single row Array Variable inside While Loop and use new result to Update Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

Picture of HTML TABLE result at END

Complete code below - IN ORDER. Note - I can change all ROWS easily and Display in HTML TABLE. the trick, at least to me, is ONLY Changing one Row to new value.

```
  <?php
  session_start();

  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id_ai, name, age, agender, $flex,hsp_plan,hcs_plan FROM quotes ");
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($id_ai, $name, $age, $agender, $flex,$hsp_plan,$hcs_plan);
  $stmt->store_result();

  echo 
  "<div class='table-responsive'>
  <table id='myTable' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
  <p><font color='#4169e1'></font></p>
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Gender</th>
  <th>Flex</th>
  <th>HSP</th>
  <th>HCS</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>";
```

I start my while loop after echo table heading so it only prints once.
then I start my loop

```
  while ($stmt->fetch()){

     $_SESSION['id_ai'] = $id_ai;
     $_SESSION['name']= $name;
     $_SESSION['age']= $age;
     $_SESSION['agender']= $agender;
     $_SESSION['flex']= $flex;
     $_SESSION['hsp_plan']= $hsp_plan;
     $_SESSION['hcs_plan']= $hcs_plan;

   $id_ai    = $_SESSION['id_ai'];
   $name     = $_SESSION['name'];
   $age      = $_SESSION['age'];
   $agender  = $_SESSION['agender'];
   $flex     = $_SESSION['flex'];
   $hsp_plan = $_SESSION['hsp_plan'];
   $hcs_plan = $_SESSION['hcs_plan'];

  $hsp_plan = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_SESSION['hsp_plan']);
  $hcs_plan = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_SESSION['hcs_plan']);
  $age      = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_SESSION['age']);
  $agender  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_SESSION['agender']);
```

I use variables to query Database table. Works perfect. I was getting duplicates on pricing 97.09 97.09 as result - the FOREACH corrected that problem.

```
  $hsp_query = mysqli_query($db,"Select sum($agender * 1 ) FROM $hsp_plan WHERE age = $age ");         
     $hsp = mysqli_fetch_array($hsp_query, MYSQLI_BOTH);                

    foreach($hsp as $key => $value)
        {
            $hsp_a = explode(' ', trim($value));
                $hsp_b[$hsp_a[1]] = $hsp_a[0];                
            $hsp_price = implode(' ', $hsp_b);
        }
```

I insert / update table with new results.

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO quotes (id_ai, id, name, age, agender, flex,hsp,hcs,bal, hsp_plan, hcs_plan) VALUES ('$id_ai', '$id_ai', '$name', '$age','$agender','$flex', '$hsp_price', '$hcs_price', '$hsp_plan','$hcs_plan')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id_ai`='$id_ai', `id`='$id_ai', `name`='$name', `age`='$age', `agender`='$agender', `flex`='$flex', `hsp`='$hsp_price', `hcs`='$hcs_price', `hsp_plan`='$hsp_plan', `hcs_plan`='$hcs_plan' ";
      if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
                    echo "";
               } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql . " " . mysqli_error($db);
               }
```

This is where I display results, and works perfectly, until I try to update. See more below.

```
  echo 
   "<tr>
   <td>$id_ai</td>
   <td>$name</td>  
   <td>$age</td>
   <td>$agender</td>
   <td><font size=2 color='#DAA520'><b><u>$flex</u></b></font></td>        
   <td align=center><font size=2 color='green'>$hsp_price<br /><a    href=#>$hsp_plan</a></font>

   <form action='hsp.php' method='POST' >
    <select onchange='this.form.submit()'' name='hs' class='form-control'>
        <option name='hs' value='hsp0'>chg</option>
        <option name='hs' value='hsp0'>x</option>
        <option name='hs' value='hsp5012'>5012</option>
        <option name='hs' value='hsp5013'>5013</option>
        <option name='hs' value='hsp5021'>5021</option>
        <option name='hs' value='hsp5022'>5022</option>
        <option name='hs' value='hsp5023'>5023</option>
        <option name='hs' value='hsp5031'>5031</option>
        <option name='hs' value='hsp5032'>5032</option>
        <option name='hs' value='hsp5033'>5033</option>
    </select>
  </form>
 </td>

   </tr>";
  }

  echo "</tbody></table></div>"; 


  /* close statement*/
  $stmt->close();   

  }
  ?>
```

This is the bottleneck HSP.PHP - notice above Form action='hsp.php ... below is code. only updates last record in loop.

hsp.php

```
  <?php
  session_start();

 $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

  $_SESSION['hs'] = $_POST['hs'];
  $_SESSION['id_ai'];

  $hs = $_SESSION['hs'];
  $id_ai = $_SESSION['id_ai'];

  $hs = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_SESSION['hs']);
  $id_ai = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_SESSION['id_ai']);

  $sql = "UPDATE quotes SET hsp_plan='$hs' where id_ai = '$id_ai' ";
               if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
          header("Location: index.php");
  }
  else {
     echo "Error updating record: " . $db->error;
   }         
 ?>
```

[image: Result Page]

Comment: Why do you set `$_SESSION['id_ai'] = $id_ai;` and then `$id_ai    = $_SESSION['id_ai'];` inside the same loop?

Comment: What's is the relevance of 'id_ai' on your table? Is it unique to the row you want to update? I'm having a terrible time trying to understand your code or your intentions.

Comment: I was simply troubleshooting . id_ai is the primary key auto increment .. id was simply a non indexed primary I used to test

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
If I understand correctly that each row of your table is a form with the same name each form has an input with the same input name and you want to make a change and update only the database row that corresponds to the row that the user changed, you could try using a `<input type='hidden' name='row_id' value='$row_id'>`

Original:
There are a few issues that you have. The primary issue that I notice is that your form submits to hsp.php but hsp.php does not appear set up to give the client a view.

Do I understand that you want the client to see the same table when they are done that they updated by making a selection? Your update code could go before the page display code, but wrapped in an `if` statement, like `if(isset($_POST['hs'])` or something.

If you give me an idea what the over all goal is then I can probably walk you though a better way to get it done. The way you have is a bit disorganized and will make it hard for people to follow.

Comment: Hello Thanks.... Yes hsp.php sends header("Location: index.php"); basically sends it back to index once it updates DB.  I'd actually prefer it to stay on same page. This designed to be a tool for us to quote hundreds at a time but we have need to drill back down and UPDATE each person individually as well.  I've used the following code without having to send form to hsp.php... how to choose the KEY or ID for the particular person or ROW I'm trying to update is where I'm struggling.

Comment: I missed the header redirect. It's certainly a different way to do things. If the rows represent individuals then what's wrong with an `update where` statement with unique id? I've never heard of making this sort of change in a loop. Your logic and your view are all mixed up.